# Low Latency RTMP Player on Android (Unity - UMP ASSET)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rtmp

I tried UMP from unity asset store, it can play RTMP video, but the delay can go to quite high if internet not stable, what I need is when internet not stable, It will jump to latest frame but not continue playing. I have no idea how to configure it to be low latency like in web flash player does.

Anyone can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a Unity Asset, contact the publisher. I am not sure what anyone on SO can do to fix it unless this is a feature already implemented in that plugin which I doubt

Comment: They told me to play around the "stream buffering time" but i still need to ask here because maybe some might use hacks to do it.